# BiometricPrompt without system provided dialog

Tags: android, biometrics, android-biometric-prompt

Is it possible to silently scan fingerprint without opening system provided dialog and deprecated `FingerPrintManager` on api 28+?

Answer (score 0):

Heyy,

I have made what you are saying just for me, and that time to share with you and its just simple.

Just watch it!!

```
private final String KEY_STORE = "AndroidKey";

    private void CheckRequirementAvailability() {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    
                fingerprintManager = (FingerprintManager) context.getSystemService(Context.FINGERPRINT_SERVICE);
                keyguardManager = (KeyguardManager) context.getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
    
                if (!fingerprintManager.isHardwareDetected()) {
    
                    login_fingerprint_status.setText("Fingerprint scanner not detected in your device.");
    
                } else if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    
                    login_fingerprint_status.setText("Allow app permission to use Fingerprint Authentication");
    
                } else if (!keyguardManager.isKeyguardSecure()) {
    
                    login_fingerprint_status.setText("Your device was not secured by any security");
    
                } else if (!fingerprintManager.hasEnrolledFingerprints()) {
    
                    login_fingerprint_status.setText("Enroll at least one fingerprint to your device");
    
                } else {
                    login_fingerprint_status.setText("Place your finger on the scanner to proceed");
    
                    generateKey();
    
                    if (cipherInit()) {
                        FingerprintManager.CryptoObject cryptoObject = (FingerprintManager.CryptoObject) new FingerprintManager.CryptoObject(cipher);
                        CancellationSignal cancellationSignal = new CancellationSignal();
                        fingerprintManager.authenticate(cryptoObject, cancellationSignal, 0, authenticationCallback(), null);
                    }
                }
    
            }
        }
    
        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
        public void generateKey() {
    
            try {
    
                keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore");
                KeyGenerator keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES, "AndroidKeyStore");
    
                keyStore.load(null);
                keyGenerator.init(new
                        KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(KEY_STORE,
                        KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT |
                                KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT)
                        .setBlockModes(KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_CBC)
                        .setUserAuthenticationRequired(true)
                        .setEncryptionPaddings(
                                KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_PKCS7)
                        .build());
                keyGenerator.generateKey();
    
            } catch (KeyStoreException | IOException | CertificateException
                    | NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidAlgorithmParameterException
                    | NoSuchProviderException e) {
    
                e.printStackTrace();
    
            }
    
        }
    
        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
        public boolean cipherInit() {
            try {
                cipher = Cipher.getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES + "/" + KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_CBC + "/" + KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_PKCS7);
            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchPaddingException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Failed to get Cipher", e);
            }
    
    
            try {
    
                keyStore.load(null);
    
                SecretKey key = (SecretKey) keyStore.getKey(KEY_STORE,
                        null);
    
                cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
    
                return true;
    
            } catch (KeyPermanentlyInvalidatedException e) {
                return false;
            } catch (KeyStoreException | CertificateException | UnrecoverableKeyException | IOException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeyException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Failed to init Cipher", e);
            }
    
        }
    
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
        private FingerprintManager.AuthenticationCallback authenticationCallback() {
    
            return new FingerprintManager.AuthenticationCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onAuthenticationError(int errorCode, CharSequence errString) {
                    super.onAuthenticationError(errorCode, errString);
                    update("" + errString, false);
                }
    
                @Override
                public void onAuthenticationFailed() {
                    super.onAuthenticationFailed();
                    update("Authentication failed", false);
                }
    
                @Override
                public void onAuthenticationHelp(int helpCode, CharSequence helpString) {
                    super.onAuthenticationHelp(helpCode, helpString);
                    update(helpString.toString(), false);
                }
    
                @Override
                public void onAuthenticationSucceeded(FingerprintManager.AuthenticationResult result) {
                    super.onAuthenticationSucceeded(result);
                    update("Authentication succeeded", true);
                }
    
    
            };
    
    
        }
    
        private void update(String cudhc, boolean b) {
    
            login_fingerprint_status.setText(cudhc);
    
            if (!b) {
                //Authentication faild //Do what you ant to do
            } else {
                //Authentication Success //Do what you ant to do
            }
        }
```

and than just call CheckRequirementAvailability() method to activate it

Add this permission in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT" />
```

Then Its done and it works with all api versions and look for that it is deperacted in 28+ API.

Remember old is gold